# AbstractAction.extend error undefined is not an object (evaluating 'el.getBoundingClientRect') odoo

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-13

I followed this tutorial https://www.oocademy.com/v13.0/tutorial/creating-and-using-javascript-assets-in-odoo-54

but i am getting this error when resizing my screen:

in the console:  `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'el.getBoundingClientRect')`

and this in odoo:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'el.getBoundingClientRect')
https://hesaby-hesaby-dev-l-1284261.dev.odoo.com/web/static/src/js/core/dom.js:554
Traceback:
computeFloatOuterWidthWithMargins@https://hesaby-hesaby-dev-l-1284261.dev.odoo.com/web/static/src/js/core/dom.js:554:26
_adapt@https://hesaby-hesaby-dev-l-1284261.dev.odoo.com/web/static/src/js/core/dom.js:543:68
later@https://hesaby-hesaby-dev-l-1284261.dev.odoo.com/web/static/lib/underscore/underscore.js:821:30
```

this is my js code

```
odoo.define("test.Dashboard", function (require) {
    const AbstractAction = require("web.AbstractAction");
    const core = require("web.core");
    const OurAction = AbstractAction.extend({
        start: function () {
            this.$el.html("hello");
        },
    });
    core.action_registry.add("test.action", OurAction);
});
```

Can you please help